# Existence and uniqueness for semilinear problem

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, parabolic-pde

Consider the following problem:

$$-\Delta u + [(u)^+]^\alpha = 0,$$

where $(\cdot)^+$ is the positive part function and $\alpha >0$. How does the theory of monotone operators provide existence and uniqueness for this problem? Do you have a reference on the topic?

Similarly, how can one prove existence and uniqueness for the parabolic problem $$u_t -\Delta u + [(u)^+]^\alpha = 0$$
under the same assumptions?